# how to constrain the output to be positive with statsmodels GLM fit_constrained

Tags: python, linear-regression, statsmodels, glm

I have a multi linear regression problem, Y = a.X1 + b.X2 + c.X3 with Y > 0

I am trying to use

```
statsmodels.GLM.fit_constrained()
```

But it's not clear in the documentation how to add constraint on the output https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.genmod.generalized_linear_model.GLM.fit_constrained.html#statsmodels.genmod.generalized_linear_model.GLM.fit_constrained

Also, my coefficients a,b and c can be negative but the output should be always positive

Thank you for your help

Comment: That's very difficult or impossible in a linear model in general. The usual way to have positive response prediction is to use an exponential mean function, loglink in GLM, e.g. Poisson uses that.

Comment: Also, statsmodels does not have support for inequality constraints in models.